# Having issues with custom delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to implement a simple delegate and seem to be having some problems. The intended result is for the user to press a button in a `UIView` that is linked to a `UIViewController` via `Outlet`. I also use the `UISearchBarDelegate` which works just fine. I am only having a problem with my custom delegate method being called.

MainViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CategoryFilterView.h"

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <UISearchBarDelegate, catFilterDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *switchViewOutlet;

// Instance Methods
- (void)searchBarLoad;

@end
```

MainViewController.m:

```
#import "MainViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController ()

@end

@implementation MainViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    CategoryFilterView *temp = [[CategoryFilterView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
    temp.delegate = self;
    self.switchViewOutlet = temp;
    [self.view addSubview:self.switchViewOutlet];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)searchBarLoad {
    UISearchBar *search = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
    search.delegate = self;
    search.showsCancelButton = YES;

    self.switchViewOutlet = search;
    [self.view addSubview:self.switchViewOutlet];

}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [self.switchViewOutlet removeFromSuperview];
    CategoryFilterView *temp = [[CategoryFilterView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
    temp.delegate = self;
    self.switchViewOutlet = temp;
    [self.view addSubview:self.switchViewOutlet];
}

- (void)searchPressed {
    // Custom Delegate Method
    NSLog(@"Test"); // This is never called
    [self.switchViewOutlet removeFromSuperview];
    [self searchBarLoad];
}

@end
```

CategoryFilterView.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol catFilterDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)searchPressed;

@end

@interface CategoryFilterView : UIView

// Button Outlets
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *byMeButtonOutlet; // Linked in .xib
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *byFriendsButtonOutlet; // Linked in .xib
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *searchButtonOutlet; // Linked in .xib

// Delegate
@property (assign, nonatomic) id<catFilterDelegate> delegate;

// Button Actions
- (IBAction)searchPressAction:(id)sender; // Linked with UIButton from .xib file

@end
```

CategoryFilterView.m:

```
#import "CategoryFilterView.h"

@implementation CategoryFilterView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code        
        NSArray *subviewArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CategoryFilterView" owner:self options:nil];
        UIView *mainView = [subviewArray objectAtIndex:0];
        [self addSubview:mainView];    }
    return self;
}

- (IBAction)searchPressAction:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Test"); // This gets called when the user presses the button from MainViewController
    [self.delegate searchPressed];
}
@end
```

I can supply more information if needed.

Comment: Are you creating this view in IB?

Comment: Yes, the view was created in IB.

Comment: Was it created in a separate nib from MainViewController, or are they both in the same storyboard?

Comment: It was, in fact, created in a separate nib. I add the nib in `CategoryFilterView.m`.

Comment: "This gets called when the user presses the button from MainViewController" -- are you talking about a button in the CategoryFilterView, or a button that's in MainViewController's view?

Comment: One more question, in addition to the one above. What is your switchViewOutlet connected to in IB if CategoryFilterView is in a different nib file?

Comment: The button is in `CategoryFilterView` which is linked with the custom nib. `switchViewOutlet` is connected in IB to `MainViewController`. I use `switchViewOutlet` to swap between a search bar and `CategoryFilterView` by setting `switchViewOutlet`. An example of this is in `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly how you have things set up, but this it what worked for me. In the CategoryFilterView.xib, I made a view with a button which was connected to the IBAction searchPressAction: in the CategoryFilterView.m file. I deleted the init code in that file (so the only code is that action method). I set MainViewController the file's owner in the CategoryFilterView xib. Then in the MainViewController, I had this code to add the subview:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.subviewArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CategoryFilterView" owner:self options:nil];
    UIView *mainView = [self.subviewArray objectAtIndex:0];
    CategoryFilterView *temp = (CategoryFilterView *)mainView;
    temp.delegate = self;
    self.switchViewOutlet = temp;
    [self.view addSubview:self.switchViewOutlet];
}
```

You would have to add similar code to the searchBarCancelButtonClicked: method to get the view back again.

**After Edit:**

It's not clear to me that you need to use a delegate at all. If you make MainViewController the file's owner of the view in the nib, then you can connect any buttons in that view to IBActions in MainViewController.m directly, without using a delegate. In that case you also don't need to subclass that view -- it can just be a UIView.

Comment: What do you mean by "I set MainViewController the file's owner in the CategoryFilterView xib?" I've never done this before.

Comment: @orbv, There's a Files Owner object at the top of the list of objects to the left of the canvas. Select it, and then on the right side, in the Identity Inspector, pick the MainViewController from the pull down list.

Comment: Thanks! Once again you have help me a great deal.

Answer (score 2):

It is a good practice to see if your delegate responds to the selector you are trying to call.

I would recommend calling it with the following code:

```
if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(searchPressed)])
{
    NSLog(@"My delegate is not nil");
    [self.delegate searchPressed];
}
```

This will tell you if your delegate is set correctly. A big possibility is that your delegate is nil but if you call a selector on a nil object it won't crash but won't do anything.

Comment: It looks like the delegate is not set correctly. The `NSLog` is not called. I don't see what I am missing though.

Comment: It looks like the actual issue may be that you are tapping the button from an item created in IB but you're setting the delegate to the version that you allocated from scratch. You are setting the delegate to the wrong item annd unnecessarily creating a new one